# Using PushView controller and Popviewcontroller make the app crashes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

In My app, I am using push and pop view controller to navigate between UIViewControlers. I have an UIViewcontroller A and UIViewController B. When I click on a button in UIViewcontroller A and use the below code

```
UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editmessage"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

I am able to navigate to UIViewController B. In B, I have a cancel button upon clicking I need to come back to A. The code I am using is below

```
NSLog(@"You did it");
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"You did it again");
```

When I press the button in UIViewcontroller A,I am able to navigate to UIViewcontroller B, the viewdidload method of B gets executed. But I am seeing the following message in log file.

```
2014-01-06 11:40:58.056 padua[5710:60b] View Did Load of editmesage controller
2014-01-06 11:40:58.231 padua[5710:60b] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2014-01-06 11:40:58.633 padua[5710:60b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

When I press the cancel button, the viewdidload of B is again getting executed. I am not sure why this is happening and the app goes to a state where only a blank background image is displayed. Please find the log below. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

CODE

```
-(IBAction)cancelMessage:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"You did it");
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"You did it again");
```

}

Logs

```
014-01-06 11:40:58.795 padua[5710:60b] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <editMessageController: 0x1900d440>.
2014-01-06 11:41:04.683 padua[5710:60b] You did it
2014-01-06 11:41:04.708 padua[5710:60b] View Did Load of editmesage controller
2014-01-06 11:41:04.769 padua[5710:60b] You did it again
```

Comment: Have you tried `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in your cancelMessage method? instead of `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Thanks for that. But viewController A is not my root view controller. I have some other controllers in the stack which is beneath ViewController A. Can I use popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES?

Comment: Yes, you can use that as well. `popViewControllerAnimated:` as stated in the documentation, also updates the navigation bar and tool bar. `popToViewController:animated:` does not.

Comment: I tried that. it went to the root view of the app.

Comment: I need to go the previous view controller i.e ViewController A. Can you please help me.

Comment: Just create ViewController A like you did B and pop to it.

Comment: @TimothyRajan please send me your code to my address in profile and I will fix and send back. then we will post the answer

Comment: Show me please the code where you initialise the UINavigationController and add it to the window

Comment: Can you please let me know which code you need? Is it Viewcontroller A  or ViewController B's code?